# Jquery не работает SlideToggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, toggle

Есть такой код .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       
         $(".row .block .icon-count #icon").click(function(){
              $(".row  .block .text-count").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle('slow');
          }); 
       
    });
```

```css
.conatiner
{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:1em;
}

.row
{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.block
{
   display:block
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.icon-count
{
   display:block
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:1em;
}

#icon
{
   cursor:pointer;
}   

.text-count
{
   display:none;
   padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="block">
                 <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="block">
                  <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="block">
                  <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="block">
                 <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="block">
                   <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="block">
                  <div class="icon-count">
                   <i id="icon">Icon</i>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-count">
                      <h1>Icon Text</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

При нажатии иконки `id="icon"` должно применятся Toggle эффект к `class="text-count"` . Помогите разобратся .

Comment: полностью код, чтобы запустить можно было.

Comment: Додайте `css` чтоб код полностью рабочии был

Comment: у Вас одинаковые id - это недопустимо (грубейшая ошибка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недопустимо использовать на одной странице одинаковые id. Следует заменить их на class, и тогда работать всё будет примерно так:

```js
$(".icon-count .icon").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().next('.text-count').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.conatiner
{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:1em;
}

.row
{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:1em;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.block
{
   display:block
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.icon-count
{
   display:block
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:1em;
}

.icon
{
   cursor: pointer;
}

.text-count
{
   display:none;
   padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, у вас много `id="icon"`, а он должен быть уникальным.
Замените `id` на `class`.

А ещё ошибка в самом JQ коде.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".row .block .icon-count").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.block').find('.text-count').slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
.conatiner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  display: block text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.icon-count {
  display: block text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}

.text-count {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="icon-count">
        <i class="icon">Icon</i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-count">
        <h1>Icon Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предоставьте пожалуйста полный код, например [тут](https://codepen.io/), и джс можно немного сократить до вида

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#icon").click(function(){
          $(".text-count").toggleClass('slow');
      }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо заменить `id="icon"` (имя не должно повторяться на странице более 1 раза) на `class="icon"`. А далее используем следующий код jQuery (в данном примере используется контекст, а также универсальный метод `.on()` для установки обработчика событий):

```
$(function() {
    $( '.icon', '.icon-count' ).on('click', function(){
        $( this ).closest( '.block' ).find( '.text-count' ).slideToggle( 'slow' );
    }); 
});
```